# Restrict access to JSP or HTML pages to a specific user group, possible using database?

Tags: servlets, authorization, servlet-filters

In my servlet based web application, there are many users. They have different roles like `admin`, `manager`, `operator` etc. After login based on their roles I would like to control the visibility of resources (HTML and JSP). E.g. `operator` can't modify or delete some data which is as usually done by `manager` or `admin` only.

Is it possible to manage in database which page can be accessed by which roles?

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/ may help.

Comment: @Dipti you can control it by hide using Filter concept.

Comment: Check out [JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html)

Comment: Check out Apache Shiro, XACML, ALFA, and Axiomatics. Spring Security too as previously mentioned. For a simple approach writing a Servlet Filter may be the easiest but that could be reinventing the wheel...